# Strict condition of program arguments in sudoers

Tags: regular-expression, sudo

Since sudoers does not support regular expressions, does anyone do as I did in the example below or is that bad?

```
user ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/program [0-9],\
                            /bin/program [0-9][0-9],\
                            /bin/program [0-9][0-9][0-9],\
                            /bin/program [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not "bad".

What you have should work OK, but it's usually better to write a wrapper script to check arguments.  For example, in `/etc/sudoers`:

```
user ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/suprogram
```

and something like the following for `/usr/local/bin/suprogram`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]{1,4}$ ]]; then
  exec program "$1"
else
  echo "Bad argument, only 1 to 4 digits allowed"
fi
```

This can be expanded upon to allow for and check more args (e.g. check that filename args are within a certain directory or match a certain pattern; or to forbid certain options being passed to sudo programs; etc).

Anything you can do in a shell script (including running other tools like awk, sed, perl, etc) can be used to validate and sanitise the arguments you pass to a program being run with sudo.

The checks aren't limited to just the arguments, either.  You can check uid, gid, whether the user is logged in locally or via ssh, date, time, network status, daemon status, available disk space, phase of the moon, whatever.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it's “usually better”. A wrapper script adds the risk of a bug in the wrapper script. A sudoer rule is less risky if the validation is simple enough.

Comment: @cas Thank you! Since the program will be a dash-script (you can not do the wrapper), I will definitely check the arguments first, but I wanted to "insure" at the level of sudoers.

Comment: @NewLinux you can use any language you like for the wrapper - including bash, dash, perl, python.  BTW, the point of writing a wrapper is that **only** the wrapper is allowed to be run with sudo.  The target program can not be run directly with sudo, but only from within the wrapper script.  Wrapper scripts should, in general, be as small and simple as possible - just the bare minimum required to run particular programs safely as root.  Everything else should be done without sudo.  This may involve writing two scripts, one for the non-root parts and one for the stuff that must be done as root.

Comment: @cas Please tell me if I use sh (dash), will this check condition be enough: `if [ "$1" -gt 1 -a "$1" -lt 10000 ]; then echo "Success"; fi 2>/dev/null`. Because this sh if the attacker enters any characters other than numbers, the error `[: Illegal number` will be shown. Whether additional verification is required, such as this: `case "${1#[+-]}" in ''|*[!0-9]*) exit ;; esac`

Comment: Obviously, it's not enough. using arithmetic tests (`-gt`, `-lt`, etc) with non-numbers is an error.   dash is not bash and doesn't support regex comparisons, so you'll have to use an external program such as grep - e.g. `if echo "$1" | grep -q -E '^[0-9]{1,4}$' ; then echo Success ; fi`.    or `^-?[0-9]{1,4}$` if negative 1 to 4 digit numbers are allowed. BTW, your test would be incorrect even if it worked - should be `-ge 1` ("greater than or equal to one", not "greater than one") otherwise 1 would fail the test. or `-ge 0` if you wanted to allow 0 too.

Comment: @cas Is the `case` checker example I gave above less reliable than grep? Since the program is run via sudo as root, I try to exclude external programs where possible, so as not to create additional risk.

Comment: Dunno, didn't look at your case example.   You are misunderstanding the source of risk, though.  Running grep as root with hard-coded args is not a problem.   Allowing non-root users to run grep (or any other program) with whatever args they like as root is risky.

Comment: BTW, `echo`  is potentially a problem when used with user-supplied args - I should have used `printf "%s" "$1"` above instead of `echo "$1"` because `dash`'s built-in `echo` interprets escape codes, including `\c` to suppress further output and `\n` for a newline - which means that args like `1\cabc` or `1\nabc` could pass the test with echo but not with printf.    `bash`'s echo can do that too, but not unless either the `xpg_echo` option is set or you use echo's `-e` option.

Comment: @cas I view grep from root (even with hard coded arguments) as a more complex program with more lines of code, consequently more surface area to attack. The compiled/binary 'dash' is 120Kbytes, and grep alone is 200Kbytes. For this reason I try to write my scripts to be run as root in dash instead of bash (which is 10 times bigger than dash). The option of checking for an integer via `case` (which I found on the Internet, and which many call very reliable and simple) only uses the internal capabilities of dash. `case "${1#[+-]}" in ''|*[!0-9]*) exit ;; esac`

Comment: you are still missing the point.   and misunderstanding the concept of attack surface too.   I give up - you are far too certain of your own "views" to waste my time trying to explain anything to you.   BTW, if you have further questions, then post another question - don't add additional questions in comments.